# How to have counters by date in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra-2.0

I would like to have a keyspace with counters distributed by date. I've been reading the docs and it says counter columns CAN'T live next to timestamps. Is there any way to achive this?

An example a want to have is:

```
material(text)  views(counter)    date(timestamp)
"phones"             234            2015-01-22
"tablets"             55            2015-01-22
"phones"              20            2015-01-21
"tablets"             50            2015-01-21
```

One approach would be to make date to be text or long but this would prevent me to get "all views from las week" for example. I looking for your experience :)

I'm usign Cassandra 2.0.11 | CQL spec 3.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use counters in conjunction with other columns, provided the other columns are either part of the partitioning key or the clustering key (i.e. the counters are the only values).

In your case since you want to filter by date, a good approach would be to set `material` as a partition key, `date` as a clustering key and `views` as your value.

by using a date as a clustering key you can order your counters by date, in reverse order. This will allow you to filter for the last week.

An example of such a schema would be:

```
CREATE TABLE views (
    material text,
    date timestamp,
    views counter,
    PRIMARY KEY(material, date)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (date DESC);
```

Comment: it worked! Thanks man, it looks like i have to read more carefully :D